# How can I strip unwanted parameters from url by NGINX

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite

How can I strip unwanted parameters from url by Nginx, for example:

http://example.com/?good=1&bad1=something&bad2=something&bad2=something&good=2

redirect to:

http://example.com/?good=1&good=2

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55374411/4862445).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx Rewrite of query params with multiple replacements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55361751/nginx-rewrite-of-query-params-with-multiple-replacements)